# IEnumerable Option strict late binding issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Private Sub EvaluateDistanceBetweenIrregularSpots(irregularWeldspots As IEnumerable)
    For Each spot1 In irregularWeldspots
       spot1.row("XUNIT") Is Nothing Then Continue For...
```

---

Issues for `spot1.row("XUNIT")` as "Option strict On disallows late binding."

Comment: Can u edit your post to add code formatting

Comment: What is the type of `spot1` and `spot2`?  Does that type have a member named `row`?  When you type the dot after either of them, what options does Intellisense give you?

Comment: Ienumerable type and we just have selected Option strict to ON after that this issue came

Answer (score 1):

The IEnumerable interface used in your code is not generic, which means that the type of objects in it are unknown.

When you do `For Each spot1 In irregularWeldspots` the actual type of spot1 is unknown so the `Object` type is assumed. There is no "row" property in class Object so that's why you get the error.

There are a couple of ways you can resolve the error. The preferred way would be to use the generic IEnumerable interface:

```
Private Sub EvaluateDistanceBetweenIrregularSpots(irregularWeldspots As IEnumerable(Of Spot))
    For Each spot1 In irregularWeldspots
       spot1.row("XUNIT") Is Nothing Then Continue For...
```

If you have a non-generic IEnumerable object, you can cast it to a generic IEnumerable easily:

```
Dim irregularWeldspots = enumerableObject.Cast<Spot>()
EvaluateDistanceBetweenIrregularSpots(irregularWeldspots) 'Now it works!
```

If for some reason you can't do this, you can always specify the type of the spot1 variable explicitely:

```
Private Sub EvaluateDistanceBetweenIrregularSpots(irregularWeldspots As IEnumerable)
    For Each spot1 As Spot In irregularWeldspots
       spot1.row("XUNIT") Is Nothing Then Continue For...
```

You can replace `Spot` by the actual type of the `spot1` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response 
But it didn't work out
As filtered datatable.asenumerable() is passed to this method

Comment: @PrasadK: You should be able to cast it to the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface (see my edit). I also proposed a second solution ;-)